# Good Practice to insure only one Spark context in application

Tags: scala, design-patterns, apache-spark, singleton

I am looking for a good way to insure that my app is only using one single Spark Context (sc). While developing I often run into errors and have to restart my Play! server to re test my modifications. 
Would a Singleton pattern be solution ?

```
object sparckContextSingleton {
  @transient private var instance: SparkContext = _
  private val conf : SparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[2]")
    .setAppName("myApp")

  def getInstance(): SparkContext = {
    if (instance == null){
      instance = new SparkContext(conf)
    }
    instance
  }  
}
```

This does not make a good job. Should I stop the SparkContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough to do the trick, important is to use val and not var.

```
object SparkContextKeeper {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkApp")
  val context= new SparkContext(conf)
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(context)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In Play you should write a plugin that exposes the SparkContext. Use the plugin's start and stop hooks to start and stop the context.

Comment: do you have any examples of this ?  how do I insure that I have only one instance of the SparkContext in the plugin's code?

Comment: For example look at the Akka plugin.